# Make text copied from absolutely positioned divs preserve whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm implementing OCR and I need to render recognized text on top of image.
I use absolutely positionated divs. Per div for each word. Buy when I select a sentence and copy it, all whitespaces are gone.

How can I make it to copy with spaces?

```
const words = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"];

const container = document.getElementById("words");

let i = 0;
for (const w of words) {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = w;
  el.style.width = 30 + "px";
  el.style.height = 10 + 'px';
  el.style.top = (i * 10) + "px";
  el.style.left = (i * 40) + "px";
  i += 1;
  
  container.appendChild(el);
  
  const space = document.createElement("span");
  space.innerHtml="&nbsp;";
  el.appendChild(space);
}
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/konstantin-edward-alikhanov/pen/YzpeNwV?editors=0110

Comment: A completely alternative route might be to write to the clipboard yourself, via the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

Use Backticks with [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
el.innerText = w + ` `;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? I have no idea how template literals relate to this question.

Comment: Or did you mean to write this? `el.innerText = \`${w} \`;`
As in, suggesting to add the space at the end of each word.